# using WHEN and CASE in Data Studio formulas

Tags: google-sheets-formula, looker-studio

I'm used to writing in JavaScript so I am approaching this thinking about SWITCH statements and of course the classic if else...

I just want to check if the data in a row is TRUE, and if it is count it. If the value is not true, don't add it to the count.

I'm thinking something like this would work:

```
CASE

WHEN is_it_true_or_false = false

THEN COUNT_DISTINCT ( id ) //using id to address that specific row and add it to the count

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by using either of the following [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements and aggregating the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) as required - [`COUNT_DISTINCT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583428) (Unique IDs of TRUE values) or [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207) (All TRUE values):

**1)  Where `is_it_true_or_false` is a Boolean OR String Field:**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(is_it_true_or_false, "((?i)TRUE)") THEN id
  ELSE NULL
END
```

**2) Where `is_it_true_or_false` is a Boolean Field:**

```
CASE
  WHEN is_it_true_or_false = TRUE THEN id
  ELSE NULL
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/eb2a1401-7431-4f5d-a015-9e1a50880ce0) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]